# How can I create shell command in linux like this: hh.sh filename -e -c?

Tags: linux, shell, command, getopts

The options are following the filename rather than hh.sh. And the following code does not work.

```
while getopts ":ec" opt; do
  case $opt in
    e)
      eflag=1
      ;;
    c)
      cflag=1
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What isn't working? How are you determined that it's failing? Also best if you ask the full question in the post, not just up in the subject line. Makes it harder to figure out what you've done/want to do.

Comment: As normal, we use hh.sh -e filename. But this assignment let me use hh.sh filename -e. How can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about something like this.

```
filename=$1
shift
while getopts ":ec" opt; do
  case $opt in
    e)
      eflag=1
      ;;
    c)
      cflag=1
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

echo $filename
echo $eflag
echo $cflag
```

grab the filename, then shift and run getopts?

Comment: how to use shift? I use your method, but it dose not work. -e is ignored.

Comment: for example, my command line is ./hh.sh 1152 -e .1152 is a pid of a process.  -e will get process name of pid 1152. How can I do?